# flex usage of (?r-s:pattern)

Tags: flex-lexer

I am trying to use the regular expression (?r-s:pattern) as mentioned in [the Flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html#Patterns).

Following code works only when i input small letter 'a' and not the caps 'A'

```
%%
[(?i:a)] { printf("color"); }
\n { printf("NEWLINE\n"); return EOL;}
. { printf("Mystery character %s\n", yytext); }
%%
```

OUTPUT

```
a
colorNEWLINE
A
Mystery character A
NEWLINE
```

Reverse is also true i.e. if i change the line (?i:a) to (?i:A) it only considers 'A' as valid input and not 'a'.
If I remove the square brackets i.e. [] it gives error as

```
"ex1.lex", line 2: unrecognized rule
```

If I enclose the "(?i:a)" then it compiles but after executing it always goes to last rule i.e. "Mystery character..."

Please let me know how to use it properly.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I am late.. :) Anyway, which `flex` version are you using, I have version `2.5.35` installed and correctly recognizes above pattern. Perhaps you're using old version!!!

Now regarding the enclosing with `[`] brackets. It works because as per `[]` regex rule it will try to match any of individual `(`, `?`, `i`, `:`, `a` or `)`. Thats why `a` gets recognized and not `A` (because it is not in the list).

Answer (score 0):

The way I read the manual, the rule without the square brackets should perform the case-insensitive matching you're looking for--I can't explain why you get an error at compile time.  But you can achieve the same behavior in one of two ways.  One, you can enumerate the upper and lower case characters in the character class:

```
%%
[Aa] { printf("color"); }
%%
```

Two, you can specify the case-insensitive scanner option, either on the command line as `-i` or `--case-insensitive` or in your .l file:

```
%%
%option case-insensitive
[a] {printf("color"); }
%%
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10497301/remote-version-of-flex-misinterprets-my-rules) also suggests that certain versions of flex have issues with (?i:) patterns.